# Python: Loop to find the neighbours of each node_id

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops, shortest-path

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(node_id):
    for arc in self._adjacency_lists[i]:
        neighbours.append(arc.head_node_id)
        i += 1
```

which gives me the output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3]
```

Where the 0th and 1st elements are the neighbours of node_id = 0, 2 the neighbour of node_id = 1, 3 of node_id = 1, 1 of node_id = 3, and 2 of node_id = 4. How can I append these neighbours to a new list so my output looks like:

```
new_list = [[1,2], [2], [3], [1], [3]]
```

Comment: Although you may working on a problem that finds the shortest path, I don't see how the shortest-path tag fits this particular question.

Comment: Also... your effort please? When you need a new list, create one. Where are you stuck at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first append an empty list for each node, then add the neighbours to that.

```
i = 0
while i < len(node_id):
    neighbours.append([])
    for arc in self._adjacency_lists[i]:
        neighbours[-1].append(arc.head_node_id)
        i += 1
```